# Child travel consent form for domestic travel within India

Tags: paperwork, india, domestic-travel

Is child travel consent form required for domestic travel within India from Mumbai to Delhi while travelling with a single parent?

Comment: It is always wise to have parental consent documents while traveling,  whether it  is required or not.

Comment: You've not specified the mode of transportation. Is it by rail, bus or air. As a child I and my sister travelled many times with only my mother by rail and air and she was never asked to present any consent document.